# Pictures Gallery and PrettyPhoto

Tags: folder

I have a SharePoint dynamic projects picture library with path /resources/gallery. The sub project folder contains images of project activity and I wanted to present the content similar to prettyphoto.

Am planning to create custom vswp using server model object but cant start without hints.

```
 /resouces/gallery
     -project1
      -img01
      -img02
     -project2
      -img01
      -img02
      -...
```

Any ideas shared will be appreciated most. Please and thanks.

Comment: You would have to elaborate a bit more here. How are you trying to read - Server object model, CSOM, JSOM?

Comment: Please add the additional details to your question by editing it.